How to drop items in between list items on iOS 18
I have a list and want to drop items at a certain index. On iOS 17, this seems to be working just fine; on iOS 18, nothing happens.
Am I doing something wrong here or is this simply an iOS 18 bug?
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var items = (1...5).map { Item(name: "\($0)") }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .dropDestination(for: String.self) { newItems, index in
                print("new", newItems, index)
            }
        }
    }
}


What exactly are you dropping? Are you sure they are URLs? Keep in mind that files from the Files app are not URLs.

Looks like the old id: .self beginner mistake.

It was just an example, I made it make a bit more sense now. Doesn't change anything about the core issue, though.

You might be encountering a bug in iOS 18. There are reports which states the issues with drag-and-drop functionalities. Particularly with the dropDestination within the List views; not behaving as expected after the iOS 18 update.
My observations shows:

Apple might have done changes to the drag-and-drop system in iOS 18 that would affect how dropDestination works within List views. This could be related to how indices are handled and how the view hierarchy updates after a drop operation.
list behaviour changes - List in SwiftUI has undergone optimisations and changes in recent iOS versions. The changes might interfere with the intended behaviour of dropDestination. Especially when you are modifying the underlying data source directly within the closure.

I can suggest an alternate method if it helps:
struct TestView: View {
@State var items: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
                .onDrop(of: [.url], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
                    if let provider = providers.first,
                       let url = provider.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) as? URL {
                        // Determine the index based on 'location' (this might require some calculation)
                        // ... (Calculate index) ... 
                        if let index = getIndex(from: location) {
                            items.insert(url.absoluteString, at: index) 
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false 
                }
        }
    }
}

private func getIndex(from location: CGPoint) -> Int? {
    // Implement logic to determine the index in 'items' based on the drop location
    // This will likely involve using the geometry of the List and its rows
    // ...
}
}

